# Issues in Neolane SDK integration in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, adobe, ios13

I am implementing `Adobe Campaign`'s **Neolane SDK** version **1.0.26** for my iOS application. While I am able to register my device successfully in the server. There are the following issues:

1. `Neolane_SDKDelegate`'s registerDeviceStatus function is not called even when the delegate is set.
2. The Adobe server is not able to send notification on iOS 13 devices while iOS 12 devices are able to receive it successfully.

I have checked using *PushNotification* utility (from RayWenderlich); both iOS 12 and iOS 13 device receive the notification. Still, the app/device doesn't receive push notification sent from AdobeCampaign server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was from campaign server side. They were using *iOS binary connector*. This could sends notifications on the legacy binary APNS server. But failed for iOS 13. Once it was replaced by *iOS HTTP/2 connector*, the problem was resolved.

Reference:
[Cofiguring Mobile Application](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/campaign-classic/using/sending-messages/sending-push-notifications/configuring-the-mobile-application.html)